# data is not showing on live asp.net website

Tags: asp.net

On my ASP.NET website, data is not showing.  I have already created database, tested it and its data by connection to remote server in SQL Server Management Studio, and it works.  The connection string is already working fine, as I tested the connection string in localhost.  It's fetching data and showing, as per my requirement.  But on the live site, the data is not loading with the page, and there is no error in the page.

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="PostAroundConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Server=162.144.46.153;Database=PostAroundDatabase;User Id=*****;Password=******;" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

This is my production server connection string. As, I place in it my Visual Studio localhost web.config it works perfectly fine. But on production server it is not fetching data not even showing any error.  Can anyone see what's wrong here?

Comment: Connection from remote server may be different from connection string on the production server. What are you using? We have nothing to look at to help you.

Comment: Felice connection string is absolutely correct because, I have tested the connection string by placing the production server name, database name, username and password. Its resulting me data accordingly but on production server data is not showing.

Comment: Login and register page are not deployed, all the other links are not connected, what is not working?

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PostAroundConnectionString"
         connectionString="Server=162.144.46.153;Database=PostAroundDatabase;User Id=*****;Password=******;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

This is my production server connection string. As, I place in it my   visualstudio localhost web.config it works perfectly fine. but on production server it is not fetching data not even showing any error please help me.

Comment: Have you tried localhost instead of the ip?

Comment: basically below login and register page is not attached yet...on pageload event i have to bind some data using datalist. The data have to show below the map and above the footer area but data is not showing.

Comment: yes i have tested my the database, the connectionstring and the data everything is working fine on my localhost but on production server my data is not displaying. Even the website not showing error. :(

Comment: I mean localhost on the connection string on production server.

Comment: see i have already created my database on production server and export the schema and data on production server. The production server is 162.144.46.153. and deployed the page on production server but data is not showing on production server

Comment: @XainuKhan If you are not seeing an exception and no data is displayed, then there are only 2 likely scenarios : (1) Your production database has no data in it, or (2) You are silently swallowing exceptions. Can you confirm that neither of these apply (and explain how you verified they did not apply?)